# Storing the output of an aggregate function to a new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, data-wrangling

I am trying to restructure some raw data, and I am a bit stuck with finding the most efficient/correct way to store the output of an aggregate function that gives the mean accuracy score for correct responses "coded as 1" for each condition in my dataset.

```
set.seed(101)
df <- data.frame(RT=rnorm(30, 100, 20), 
                 Condition=sample(c("Green","Red","Blue"),10, replace=T),
                 Image=sample(c("Cow", "Horse", "Giraffe"), 10, replace=T),
                 Response=sample(c("Cow", "Horse", "Giraffe"), 10, replace=T))
                 
df$Accuracy <- ifelse(df$Image == df$Response, 1, 0)

con_avg_accuracy <- aggregate(Accuracy~Condition, df, FUN = mean)
con_avg_accuracy <- data.frame(Condition=c("acc_g","acc_m","acc_n"), Accuracy=con_avg_accuracy$Accuracy)
```

This is an idea of what I have been trying to do, and it works, to a point, in that it stores my aggregate output to the data frame and changes the condition names, but I feel like there is a better way to do this (perhaps by piping it in?). Also, I cannot seem to figure out how I would add the values of output to the data frame with the new condition names being the columns and each mean score for the condition being in the rows.

I hope that makes sense, and any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Could you give an example of your desired output? I'm afraid I do not quite understand what you are trying to get at.

Comment: I am also quite unclear. Your code is quite short, so though it sounds like you're looking for advice along the lines of "here is how you are *meant* to do the thing you are doing", the way you're doing it right now is ~okay~. The only thing I would suggest doing is switching your `con_avg_accuracy <- data.frame(Condition=c("acc_g","acc_m","acc_n"), Accuracy=con_avg_accuracy$Accuracy)` line to something more like `con_avg_accuracy$Condition <- c("acc_g","acc_m","acc_n")`

Comment: Not shure. If I understand the question correctly, the better way to do that ist through `data.table` as in: `library(data.table); setDT(df); df[, mean(Image == Response), Condition]`.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity in my question. I think I was trying to ask two things at the same time, which made it confusing. To stick with one thing, what I am trying to do is take the output of the aggregate function that I have assigned to the new variable "con_avg_accuracy" and rename the conditions from "C", "H", "G" , to "acc_c","acc_h","acc_g" (sorry for the typo of those names in my code). I then want to assign these new conditions as columns in a new data frame with their appropriate mean outputs from the aggregate. I haven't had any luck working out how to do this..

Comment: @jdtrulson if say `df$x` is `c( "C", "H", "G")`, then `df$x <- paste0("acc_", tolower(df$x))` should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is compact enough, and the pip won't be less. Just like this:

```
con_avg_accuracy <-  df%>%group_by(Condition)%>%
  summarize(Accuracy = mean(Accuracy))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Condition mean_Acc
  <fct>        <dbl>
1 Blue         0.286
2 Green        0.5  
3 Red          0
```

The key is the rest of your intended operations, following your last line of code. see below:

```
con_avg_accuracy %<>% t()
##put first row as column names, and then remove first row
colnames(con_avg_accuracy) <- con_avg_accuracy[1,]
con_avg_accuracy %<>%tail(-1)%>%as.data.frame()
row.names(con_avg_accuracy) <- NULL 
 
##gives
con_avg_accuracy
      acc_g     acc_m     acc_n
1 0.2857143 0.5000000 0.0000000
```

ps. your 'c("acc_g","acc_m","acc_n")' seems not to be consistent with 'Condition', and the values are different from the example you give in the comment.

Comment: don't forget to `ungroup()`! :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help and your comments, and I'm sorry that my question wasn't clear. Because I am going to be looping through a large number of files, extracting key information, and then compiling those, so I don't want to add to the original dataset. Instead I am trying to create an output like this `data.frame(acc_h=c(0.3333), acc_c=c(0.6000), acc_g=c(0.5000))` from the aggregate.

Comment: @jdtrulson Ok. Then you would like the summarize() method instead.

Comment: @Jinjin Thanks so much for this, and for your advice. I know I made a mess of my question, and I will definitely try to be more clear next time in what I am trying to ask, but  your response and script is exactly what I was looking for.